# Target Platform Failing to create Shared Libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, cmake

I am using cmake to compile code.In in ,i have used the SHARED option to create Shared Library.However ,on compiling using cmake I am getting the error :

```
 ADD_LIBRARY for library GenericUSMModules is used with the SHARED option, but the target platform supports only STATIC libraries. Building
 it STATIC instead. This may lead to problems.

 ADD_LIBRARY for library XXXaUSMModules is used with the SHARED option, but the target platform supports only STATIC libraries. Building
 it STATIC instead. This may lead to problems.
```

and it is creating libGenericUSMModules.a(Static library) and libXXXUSMModules.a instead of the so files. I want to know if it is possible to create Shared Library For each of the archive files(like libGenericUSMModules.so and libXXXUSMModules.a ) while linking it with a static library libGCVCore.a present in the same location.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was the cmake i was using.It was a old version.I Installed the latest version of the Cmake and the code compiled without any problem.